# How to Import a BACPAC file to Azure SQL and Overwrite Existing Database?

Tags: sql-server, azure-sql-database

Say I have a local database named MyDatabase. I want to move it to Azure SQL and replace an existing database currently residing there named MyDatabase. I know how to create a BACPAC file locally. I know how to import the BACPAC to my Azure storage account. However, once the BACPAC is in Azure storage, I don't know the preferred way of overwriting the existing MyDatabase database with the copy in storage. I could import the BACPAC file and create a second database, then delete the first, and rename the database just imported. However, is the best or preferred way of doing this?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You are correct.  In Azure you cannot restore on an existing database, only ["a new or empty one"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/sqlpackage/sqlpackage-import?view=sql-server-ver15).

- You have to restore with a different name.
- Delete old database
- Rename new one to old database name.

You have few ways to restore from .BACPAC file.

1. You can do it directly from your on prem .BACPAC location by using
   `.\sqlpackage.exe` command line tool.

   .\sqlpackage.exe /a:Import /sf:C:\filename.bacpac /tsn:ServerName.database.windows.net /tdn:destinationDBName `
   /tu:adminaccountName@serverName /tp:$credentialPW
2. You can also use the copy that you uploaded in your storage account.

   $ResourceGroupName = "RGName"
   $ServerName = 'ServerName'
   $DatabaseName = "DestinationDBName"

   $StorageName = "StorageAccountName"
   $StorageKeyType = "StorageAccessKey"
   $StorageUri = "http://$StorageName.blob.core.windows.net/swwstoragecontainer/BackpacFileName.bacpac"
   $StorageKey = "***********************************"

   $credential = Get-Credential

   $importRequest = New-AzureRmSqlDatabaseImport -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName -ServerName $ServerName `-DatabaseName $DatabaseName -StorageKeytype $StorageKeyType -StorageKey $StorageKey`
   -StorageUri $StorageUri -AdministratorLogin $credential.UserName -AdministratorLoginPassword $credential.Password `
   -Edition Standard -ServiceObjectiveName S0 -DatabaseMaxSizeBytes 50000

   Get-AzureRmSqlDatabaseImportExportStatus -OperationStatusLink $importRequest.OperationStatusLink
3. In portal you can directly import the `.BACPAC` file into your server as a database.

Comment: It appears I can also use SSMS to deploy my local copy to Azure SQL by right-clicking on the database in SSMS, choosing Tasks and then Deploy Database to Microsoft SQL Azure. Have you done this?

Comment: You are correct, yes I did. This is one of the easiest  way I show in my presentation. Details [here](http://sqlworldwide.com/how-to-migrate-a-sql-database-to-microsoft-azure-sql-v12/).

Comment: I've tried this script and the one using the newer `Az` PS modules - but both just give me a 500 error with no further explanation :(

Comment: @IanGrainger with new Az module commands name is different. For example `New-AzureRmSqlDatabaseImport `  does not exist in the new module, you need to use  `New-AzSqlDatabaseImport`.

Comment: @RandyMinder WOW! Just saw this capability! That's awesome, had no idea!!!!! WIsh this was an answer *someplace* so I could give you some points too!

Answer (score 8):

> > In Azure you cannot restore on an existing database. (c)

Apparently, not really. You CAN restore a .bacpac file into existing Azure SQL database, for example, in a case when you really need to keep *the same* instance of Azure SQL database, as it's incorporated in Azure environment. A necessary condition for that is: the target DB must be empty, i.e. like just created as new. But if you already have a target DB, which is not empty (of course!), you can "clean" the database, running the following script in its context, being logged in as a superuser:

```
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(2000)

WHILE EXISTS(SELECT TOP(1) * FROM SYS.TRIGGERS WHERE is_ms_shipped = 0)
BEGIN
    SELECT TOP(1) @sql = 'DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS [' + [name] + '] ON ' + parent_class_desc COLLATE database_default --SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
    FROM SYS.TRIGGERS
    WHERE is_ms_shipped = 0
    PRINT @sql
    EXEC (@sql)
END

WHILE EXISTS(SELECT TOP(1) * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.ROUTINES WHERE ROUTINE_TYPE = 'PROCEDURE')
BEGIN
    SELECT TOP(1) @sql = 'DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS [' + ROUTINE_SCHEMA + '].[' + ROUTINE_NAME + ']'
    FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.ROUTINES
    WHERE ROUTINE_TYPE = 'PROCEDURE'
    PRINT @sql
    EXEC (@sql)
END

WHILE EXISTS(SELECT TOP(1) * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.ROUTINES WHERE ROUTINE_TYPE = 'FUNCTION')
BEGIN
    SELECT TOP(1) @sql = 'DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS [' + ROUTINE_SCHEMA + '].[' + ROUTINE_NAME + ']'
    FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.ROUTINES
    WHERE ROUTINE_TYPE = 'FUNCTION'
    PRINT @sql
    EXEC (@sql)
END

WHILE EXISTS(SELECT TOP(1) * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS WHERE CONSTRAINT_TYPE='FOREIGN KEY')
BEGIN
    SELECT TOP(1) @sql = 'ALTER TABLE [' + TABLE_SCHEMA + '].[' + TABLE_NAME + '] DROP CONSTRAINT [' + CONSTRAINT_NAME + ']'
    FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS
    WHERE CONSTRAINT_TYPE='FOREIGN KEY'
    PRINT @sql
    EXEC (@sql)
END

WHILE EXISTS(SELECT TOP(1) * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_TYPE = 'VIEW' AND TABLE_SCHEMA != 'sys')
BEGIN
    SELECT TOP(1) @sql = 'DROP VIEW [' + TABLE_SCHEMA + '].[' + TABLE_NAME + ']'
    FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
    WHERE TABLE_TYPE = 'VIEW' AND TABLE_SCHEMA != 'sys'
    PRINT @sql
    EXEC (@sql)
END

WHILE EXISTS(SELECT TOP(1) * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_TYPE = 'BASE TABLE' AND TABLE_NAME != '__MigrationHistory')
BEGIN
    SELECT TOP(1) @sql = 'DROP TABLE [' + TABLE_SCHEMA + '].[' + TABLE_NAME + ']'
    FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
    WHERE TABLE_TYPE = 'BASE TABLE' AND TABLE_NAME != '__MigrationHistory'
    PRINT @sql
    EXEC (@sql)
END

--SELECT * FROM SYS.TYPES WHERE is_user_defined = 1
--SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_TYPE = 'BASE TABLE' AND TABLE_NAME != '__MigrationHistory'
--SELECT * FROM SYS.TRIGGERS WHERE is_ms_shipped = 0
--DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS [backup_objects] ON DATABASE
```

Last 4 statements are optional. First 3 of them are for checking/viewing of some parameters, and last one is used for dropping a specific database-level trigger if it exists.

After that, you can restore the .bacpac file you have, to the target DB using the standard sqlpackage.exe utility, running it in the Administrative-elevated command line window, like this:

```
“C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\140\DAC\bin\sqlpackage.exe” /a:Import /sf:"C:\Users\[username1]\Documents\SQL Server Management Studio\DAC Packages\[SourceDBName.bacpac]" /tsn:[azureSQLServerName].database.windows.net /tdn:[TargetAzureSQLDBName] /tu:[DBAdminLogin] /tp:[DBAdminPassword]
```

Just replace [braced_values] with real ones, and it should work. Upon running, the utility may show a warning message, displayed with yellow color, like this:

> Initializing deployment   The object [data_0] exists in the target,
>   but it will not be dropped even though you selected the 'Generate drop
>   statements for objects that are in the target database but that are
>   not in the source' check box.   The object [log] exists in the target,
>   but it will not be dropped even though you selected the 'Generate drop
>   statements for objects that are in the target database but that are
>   not in the source' check box.

You can just disregard it. Depending of the database size and complexity, the restoring process may take a long time, so make sure to wait until it finishes, displaying the message: *Successfully imported database.*

Hope that helps.

Comment: When you have custom schema's, you can also drop these with same kind of sql for SYS.schemas + where name not in ('dbo', 'guest','INFORMATION_SCHEMA', 'sys', 'db_owner',  'db_accessadmin','db_securityadmin','db_ddladmin','db_backupoperator','db_datareader','db_datawriter','db_denydatareader','db_denydatawrite')